# IP address does not match in Laravel

Tags: laravel, ip

I used bellow the code in Laravel 
**request()->ip();** 
it showed me an ip address, suppose: *103.161.148.48*

 
But when I check in different online site, some sites are showing - 
*103.161.148.43*, 
*103.161.148.21*, 
*103.161.148.13*, 
*103.161.148.46*  
that means, always the last two digit is changing.

Why it's happening ? And what is the actual solution  ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems your ip address is dynamic(ie. not static), in that case you can try below solution to compare it.

```
<?php
    if (strpos(\Request::ip(), '103.161.148') !== false) {
        echo 'matched';
    }
?>
```